# How to verify google authenticator code using passport-2fa-totp?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am implementing two factor authentication using passportjs module  [passport-2fa-totp][1]http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-2fa-totp/

I am able to successfully register user and store its key.

I am not able to verify totp-code generated by google authenticator app I am using the following code as reference,

`passport.use(new TwoFAStartegy(function (username, password, done) {

```
// 1st step verification: username and password

User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
    if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
    return done(null, user);
});}, function (user, done) {
// 2nd step verification: TOTP code from Google Authenticator

if (!user.secret) {
    done(new Error("Google Authenticator is not setup yet."));
} else {
    // Google Authenticator uses 30 seconds key period
    // https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format

    var secret = GoogleAuthenticator.decodeSecret(user.secret);
    done(null, secret, 30);
}}));`
```

I am not able to understand the second step of verification. First of all I don't have access to `code` field here which needs to be validated and I  am also not able to fetch any proper output. It is just returning me `Invalid username or password` which isn't the case.

Help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that you are getting `username`, `password` and `code` in these exact fields only and not in any other field, because `passport-2fa-totp` assumes that you are getting in these fields only.

`code` field will be passed to the second callback of `TwoFAStartegy` and `verify` fn will verify the the code.

Maybe, you can get additional info if you do this,

```
new TwoFAStartegy({ passReqToCallback: true }, (username, password, done) => 
{
// First Callback
}, (req, user, verify) => {
console.log(req) // The request Object
// Use req here
})
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Actually my error was that I was using wrong secret key in Google Authenticator, though thanks for helping out. Just for someone going through question `passReqToCallback` param is optional.